# Failure in getting data from JSON using setData in Highcharts using pure JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, highcharts

Guys I am new to Highcharts so have been trying to get Data Dynamically from a JSON file.I declared an array in JSON file but even if I looped through it in ajax I am not getting the Correct Values.
I tried the Following Methods in AJAX

1st Method:

```
    <script>
         window.onload=function()
            {
                var Request=new XMLHttpRequest();
                Request.open("GET","charts.json");
                Request.onload = function()
                {
                    var datass=JSON.parse(Request.responseText);
                    parsess(datass);
                }
                Request.send();
            }  
         function parsess(datae)
          {
              let x="";
              chart.setTitle({text:datae.title})
              for(let i in datae.data)
                  {
                      x = x + datae.data[i] + ",";
                  }
              console.log(x);
              chart.series[0].setData([x]);
          }
      </script>
```

2nd Method:

```
function parsess(datae)
      {
          let x="";
          chart.setTitle({text:datae.title})
          for(let i=0;i<datae.data[i].length;i++)
          chart.series[0].setData([datae.data[i]]);
      }
```

I know for sure Method 2 is wrong because while looping it leaves the previous values. So please give me a solution guys...

My JSON:

```
{
    "title":"my first chart",
    "name": "akhil",
    "data":[13,15,17]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `chart.series[0].setData(datae.data)`?

Comment: If i use tat I am only getting the first value 13

Comment: ya I got it bruh thanks...But whats wrong in using setData([datae.data])

Comment: As its an array I used setData([datae.data])..But as u advised, I got the result with setData(datae.data)

Comment: `datae.data` is already an array so `setData(datae.data)` is the same as `setData([13, 15, 17])`.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot bruh for ur valuable time nd effort. I am struggling from past one hour...

Comment: This is why using *informative* variable names is important.

Comment: Really I have seen in number of tutorials asking us to use correct varibale names. But really I struggle a lot while choosing those names. May be due to lack of Experience as I am a fresher.... Thanks for the advice @CertainPerformance